# How to start a Nodejs server with options?

Tags: node.js

My computer runs Windows10 Enterprise.

I found [this repo](https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs#user-content-part-b-steps-for-nodejs) for creating a Nodejs server for tchatbot. As you can see there are options for starting the server. I tried to execute this command : `node app.js DF_PROJECT_ID="agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo" DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH="D:\Docs\TchatBot\clé_account_service_agent_human_operator\agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo-3349b2f01974.json"`

But I got error : `You need to specify a path to a service account keypair in environment variable DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH`

So what is wrong ?

Comment: remove the quotes around your string

Comment: make it a start script (i.e. so `npm start` runs node for you) and use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) in that script for those environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically same as jfriend00's solution, but I add `node app.js` in the end.  And you just follow below sequence to run command.

```
set DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH="D:\Docs\TchatBot\clé_account_service_agent_human_operator\agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo-3349b2f01974.json"
set DF_PROJECT_ID="agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo"
node app.js
```

By the way, if you use linux system or macOS, you'll use following command to start server.

(Just one line)
`DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH="D:\Docs\TchatBot\clé_account_service_agent_human_operator\agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo-3349b2f01974.json" DF_PROJECT_ID="agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo" node app.js`

Comment: I get error `'DF_PROJECT_ID' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file`

Comment: @pheromix I update my answer, it's basically same as jfriend00's solution. But, after you setup, you need to run `node app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set these in the environment in a command shell before running nodejs from that command shell:

```
set DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH="D:\Docs\TchatBot\clé_account_service_agent_human_operator\agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo-3349b2f01974.json"
set DF_PROJECT_ID="agent-human-handoff-sampl-jseo"
```

Then, you you can run your program and these variables will be in the environment that your node program inherits.  If you want to automate this, you can create a small batch file that will set them and then run your program.  Keep in mind that setting environment variables like this sets them on for programs run from the current command shell, not other command shells and not for programs run other ways.

After setting those, your environment is now configured and you would run your program just as always:

```
node app.js
```

Comment: After setting the environment variables, how is the command to start the server ?

Comment: @pheromix - Same as always `node app.js`.  Sorry, but I assumed you knew how to run a node.js program and this was merely a question about configuring environment variables.

Comment: I thought there would be other options to add among `node app.js` :)

Comment: @pheromix - Once you set up the environment in a command shell, any program you run from that command shell will inherit that environment so you just start programs normally and they get that environment.